# Cleanest way to combine two shorts to an int

Tags: c++

I have two 16-bit shorts (s1 and s2), and I'm trying to combine them into a single 32-bit integer (i1). According to the spec I'm dealing with, s1 is the most significant word, and s2 is the least significant word, and the combined word appears to be signed. (i.e. the top bit of s1 is the sign.)

What is the cleanest way to combine s1 and s2?

I figured something like

```
const utils::int32 i1 = ((s1<<16) | (s2));
```

would do, and it seems to work, but I'm worried about left-shifting a short by 16.

Also, I'm interested in the idea of using a union to do the job, any thoughts on whether this is a good or bad idea?

Answer (score 14):

What you are doing is only meaningful if the shorts and the int are all unsigned. If either of the shorts is signed and has a negative value, the idea of combining them into a single int is meaningless, unless you have been provided with a domain-specific specification to cover such an eventuality.

Comment: I agree that the code posted has a sign extension bug, and that the request of "combining" two in16_tss to an int32_t is rather odd. But I don't think it's necessarily meaningless, in the sense that one could define some semantics for the operation.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the interface to the hardware is splitting a signed integer into 2, and then sending it, because it's got a MSW and a LSW, but it's apparently in 2's complement signing. So I need to recombine the data sensibly from that.

Answer (score 8):

What you've got looks nearly correct, but will probably fail if the second part is negative; the implicit conversion to int will probably sign-extend and fill the upper 16 bits with ones. A cast to unsigned short would probably prevent that from happening, but the best way to be sure is to mask off the bits.

```
const utils::int32 combineddata = ((data.first<<16) | ((data.second) & 0xffff));
```

Comment: Excellent, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Indeed the implicit conversion to int will cause problems. For example `data.first<<16` will also invoke undefined behavior in this posted code, if data.first is negative. Therefore this is not a good solution. Overall, it is not a good idea to use shift operators together with signed numbers. Better solution: `uint32_t u32 = (uint32_t)data.first<<16 | (uint32_t)data.second; combineddate = (int32_t)u32;`

Comment: @Lundin casting `data.second` to `uint32_t` will sign-extend it, causing the most significant 16 bits (left half) of `u32` to be all 1s if `data.second` is negative. Instead, cast `data.second` to a `uint16_t`: `(uint32_t)data.first<<16 | (uint16_t)data.second`

Comment: @Phil No, that's nonsense. Converting something to an unsigned type doesn't cause sign extension. Sign extension happens when you go from a small type with negative value to a larger signed type.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post but the quality of the present posted answers is depressing...

These are the issues to consider:

- Implicit integer promotion of shorts (or other small integer types) will result in an operand of type `int` which is signed. This will happen regardless of the signedness of the small integer type. Integer promotion happens in the shift operations and in the bitwise OR.
- In case of the shift operators, the resulting type is that of the promoted left operand. In case of bitwise OR, the resulting type is obtained from "the usual arithmetic conversions".
- Left-shifting a negative number results in undefined behavior. Right-shifting a negative number results in implementation-defined behavior (logical vs arithmetic shift). Therefore signed numbers should not be used together with bit shifts in 99% of all use-cases.
- Unions, arrays and similar are poor solutions since they make the code endianess-dependent. In addition, type punning through unions is also not well-defined behavior in C++ (unlike C). Pointer-based solutions are bad since they will end up violating "the strict aliasing rule".

A proper solution will therefore:

- Use operands with types that are guaranteed to be unsigned and will not be implicitly promoted.
- Use bit-shifts, since these are endianess-independent.
- Not use some non-portable hogwash solution with unions or pointers. There is absolutely nothing gained from such solutions except non-portability. Such solutions are however likely to invoke one or several cases of undefined behavior.

It will look like this:

```
int32_t  i32 = (int32_t)( (uint32_t)s1<<16 | (uint32_t)s2 );
```

Any other solution is highly questionable and at best non-portable.

Comment: Heh. To be honest, looking back with 8 years more experience, the only people who could really have answered this are the designers of the hardware API themselves.I wondered at the time if they were using a known standard method of combining, but...

Comment: @deworde What do you mean "hardware API"? This code is about as close to the metal as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody posted it, this is what the union would look like. But the comments about endian-ness definitely apply.

Big-endian:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint16_t high;
        uint16_t low;
    } pieces;
    uint32_t all;
} splitint_t;
```

Little-endian:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint16_t low;
        uint16_t high;
    } pieces;
    uint32_t all;
} splitint_t;
```

Comment: note that the spec provides zero guarantees about this. It is widely used in C especially, and I doubt any compiler would intentionally break it, but it is strictly speaking undefined behavior. You can't in general write to one member of a struct and read from another.

Comment: Note that the standard does not guarantee that `all` will have any sensible data after assigning to `high` and `low`, and vice-versa. This solution is not portable.

Comment: There is no reason to use a union for this, all you achieve is portability problems. And type punning is not well-defined in C++, unlike C.

Answer (score 1):

Try projecting data.second explicite to short type, like:

```
const utils::int32 combineddata = ((data.first<<16) | ((short)data.second));
```

edit: I am C# dev, probably the casting in your code language looks different, but idea could be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You want to cast data.first to an int32 before you do the shift, otherwise the shift will overflow the storage before it gets a chance to be automatically promoted when it is assigned to combined data.

Try:

```
const utils::int32 combineddata = (static_cast<utils::int32>(data.first) << 16) | data.second;
```

This is of course assuming that data.first and data.second are types that are guaranteed to be precisely 16 bits long, otherwise you have bigger problems.

I really don't understand your statement "if data.second gets too big, the | won't take account of the fact that they're both shorts."

*Edit:* And Neil is absolutely right about signedness.

Comment: In the case of shorts I'm not sure this is necessary.  The standard has:  "The operands shall be of integral or enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand".  Therefore, the short will be promoted to an int implicitly.

Comment: Huh. I did not know that - I guess it's because I'm always super-paranoid about data type sizes. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: It's good to be paranoid because the cast would definitely be required on platforms with a 16-bit int!

Comment: Paranoia is good.  So is learning the standard.  Not to mention realizing that implementations often don't quite implement the whole and exact standard.

Answer (score -1):

Using a union to do the job looks like a good choice, but is a portability issue due to endian differences of processors.  It's doable, but you need to be prepared to modify your union based on the target architecture.  Bit shifting is portable, but please write a function/method to do it for you.  Inline if you like.

As to the signedness of the shorts, for this type of operation, it's the meaning that matters not the data type.  In other words, if s1 and s2 are meant to be interpreted as two halves of a 32 bit word, having bit 15 set only matters if you do something that would cause s2 to be sign extended.  See Mark Ransoms answer, which might be better as

```
inline utils::int32 CombineWord16toLong32(utils::int16 s1, utils::int16 s2)
{
    return ((s1 <<16) | (s2 & 0xffff));
}
```