# Combine four 8-bit unsigned ints into one 32-bit unsigned int

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

Given an array of four 8-bit unsigned ints, for example a [32-bit RGBA color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space)

```
rgba = [255, 255, 255, 255] # white
```

what is the most efficient way to combine these four [Fixnums](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Fixnum.html) into a single 32-bit [Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Integer.html)?

Currently, I'm using pack and unpack:

```
rgba.pack('C*').unpack('L')[0] #=> 4294967295

# Check work: same value as corresponding hex literal
0xffffffff #=> 4294967295
```

but I wonder if there's a more efficient way.  I found this C++ question:

[Cleanest way to combine two shorts to an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294649/cleanest-way-to-combine-two-shorts-to-an-int)

and I think `<<` is a "shift" and `|` is a "mask", but I don't know enough about those operators, and have never used them in ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift each element by *24 - (index * 8)*, then OR them all together:

```
rgba = [255, 255, 255, 255]
rgba[0] << 24 | rgba[1] << 16 | rgba[2] << 8 | rgba[3]
```

I didn't shift `rgba[3]` because shifting by zero has no effect.

Some measurements:

**Using `unpack`**

```
Benchmark.measure do
  100_000.times do
    rgba = [255, 255, 255, 255]
    rgba.pack('C*').unpack('L')[0]
  end
end
```

Result:

```
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fe137005350
 @cstime=0.0,
 @cutime=0.0,
 @label="",
 @real=0.146899,
 @stime=0.0,
 @total=0.1399999999999999,
 @utime=0.1399999999999999>
```

**Using bitwise operators**

```
Benchmark.measure do
  100_100.times do
    rgba = [255, 255, 255, 255]
    rgba[0] << 24 | rgba[1] << 16 | rgba[2] << 8 | rgba[3]
  end
end
```

Result:

```
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fd66438fd28
 @cstime=0.0,
 @cutime=0.0,
 @label="",
 @real=0.088995,
 @stime=0.0,
 @total=0.08000000000000007,
 @utime=0.08000000000000007>
```

Comment: Cool.  It's nice that you can chain the ORs without a bunch of parens like in the C++ example.  Big thanks for including benchmarks!

Comment: @JaredBeck I'm fairly certain most of the parens in that example are unnecessary, but are included for readability (`|` and `&` have higher precedence than `<<` - according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence))