# how to store 2 numbers inside into a 32 bit number in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two integer numbers and I would like put them into a 32 bit number so that 0 to 16 first bit would be for first number and 17 to 32 other bits would be for another number. How to do this work?

Comment: Think in binary and write code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294649/cleanest-way-to-combine-two-shorts-to-an-int

Comment: Do not try to write something to bit 32.

Answer (score 0):

`int32_t  i32 = (int32_t)( (uint32_t)s1<<16 | (uint32_t)s2 );`

also see [Cleanest way to combine two shorts to an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294649/cleanest-way-to-combine-two-shorts-to-an-int)